Can we delete this revenge account from Stack Exchange?
I looked at the deleted answers to What does 了mean in 衣服也落在了房间内, and is it pronounce le or liao?
Someone there previously posted answers under someone else's name in a clearly deliberate attempt to defame them.  They're some kind of revenge posts.  The posts are now deleted (although only soft-deleted), but the revenge account still exists here, albeit dormant.  Thus, the victim's name is still visible.
The user does not seem have made any contributions to Stack Exchange whatsoever, so I propose deleting this account entirely.  Or, at the very least, please remove the victim's (likely real) name from this account: it's surely not their account.
Question: Can we delete this revenge account from Stack Exchange?

When someone creates an account with a person's full name and posts "I am an [...] and a [...] who will [...]", it seems pretty revenge-y.

It's possible they're not on Stack Exchange at all, e.g., the perpetrator just wanted their victim's real name and their comments to get high search rankings, etc., just to hurt them.
